# Ubuntu Not Waking From Suspend

Tags: 12.04, login, suspend

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (not wubi, usb install) alongside Windows 7 on my Toshiba Satellite Laptop Series L655D-S5050

I have a couple of issues, Ubuntu will not wake from suspend when closing the lid. It will show the Ubuntu screen then go to black and spit out some quick text before the screen will just flicker, as if trying to wake up. I've been googling around looking for a fix but nothing seems to help. Maybe it has something to do with the drivers? I checked additional drivers in the system settings, but it says there are no drivers present. Any ideas?

Also, this issue isn't present all the time. But sometimes when I go to shutdown or restart Ubuntu, it will just loops to the login screen.

Thank you, for any input or help! Also I can get some logs of these issues, but not really sure how to go about all of that. I'm not to familiar with ubuntu, as i've only been using the desktop version for a couple months now.

Answer (score -1):

For the perpetual shutdown problem, unplug any usb devices when the computer is booting or shutting down. I've been pretty lazy lately so I only know the workarounds and not the voodoo behind them, but it keeps my laptop from hanging up.

For your issue resuming from sleep, see if you can drop to a console with `ctrl + alt + F2`  when it hangs up, and then switch right back to tty7 with `ctrl + alt + F7`

[Saw this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124399/laptop-screen-goes-blank-after-waking-from-sleep?rq=1) thread on the side of the page and its got some more ideas to try.
Good Luck!